# Vectors multiplied by scalars

Tags: vectors

When we multiply a vector by a scalar, why does the magnitude of the vector increase by a factor of the scalar. How do we intuitively understand why this is?

Comment: Do you understand why this works for the real and complex numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Say $$\bar x = x_1 \hat {i} + x_2 \hat {j} + x_3 \hat {k}$$ Using this gives, $$|\bar x| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$$ Now say we multiply our initial vector with $k$, this gives us a new vector, $$\bar{x'} = (kx_1) \hat {i} + (kx_2) \hat {j} + (kx_3) \hat {k}$$ This gives us, $$|\bar{x'}| = \sqrt{(kx_1)^2 + (kx_2)^2 + (kx_3)^2} = \sqrt{k^2(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)} = k\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2} = k|\bar x|$$ i.e.,
$$|\bar{x'}| = k|\bar x|$$
Hence, the magnitude of new vector ($\bar{x'} = k \bar{x}$) increases by a factor of the scalar multiplied to the initial vector.